# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE with Docker and NGINX

Tags: php, docker, symfony, nginx, docker-compose

I have a problem with my Docker and NGINX config?

Everything is running but my web page returns a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Here is my NGINX config:

```
server {
listen 8443;

server_name api.test.dv;
root /api/public;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    internal;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}
}
```

My docker-compose :

```
version: "3"

services:
    nginx:
        image: "bitnami/nginx:latest"
        ports:
            - "11083:8443"
        volumes:
            - "./docker/nginx/vhost.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/app.conf"
            - .:/api
        depends_on:
            - php

    php:
        build: "docker/php"
        volumes:
            - .:/api:cached
        working_dir: /api
        user: 1000:1000
        depends_on:
            - database
            - redis

    database:
        image: "postgres:latest"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_DB: app
        ports:
            - "11032:5432"

    redis:
        image: "redis:3.2.11"
```

NGINX logs are good, no error.

I use Docker desktop on Mac OS.

I have really no idea about my problem.

Comment: Last time I had no idea what was the problem disabling the buffering worked. You can at least try it so you'll know where to look: `fastcgi_buffering off;`

Comment: I have same problem with you

Answer (score 0):

in my case, ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (and ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) was fixed by

- remove `server_name localhost;` to fix DNS issues with IPv6, and access the server by its IP address (127.0.0.1) instead of its hostname (localhost)
- set `keepalive_timeout 65;`
- set `worker_processes 3;`